# list of DataFrames as an argument of function/loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have multiple `DataFrame` and I need to perform various operations on them. I want to put them in one `list` to avoid listing them all the time as in the example bellow:

```
for df in (df1, df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7):
df.columns=['COUNTRY','2018','2019']
df.replace({':':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({' ':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df["2018"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2018"], downcast="float")
df["2019"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2019"], downcast="float")
```

I tried to make a list of them (`DataFrames=[df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7]`) but it's working neither in the loop or as an argument of a function.

```
for df in (DataFrame):
df.columns=['COUNTRY','2018','2019']
df.replace({':':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df.replace({' ':''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
df["2018"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2018"], downcast="float")
df["2019"] = pd.to_numeric(df["2019"], downcast="float")
```

Comment: could you post the error you got

Comment: for function I get the error: 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment

Comment: for loop no error but the operations inside it just don't work

Comment: is your indentation correct?

Answer (score 1):

you can place the dataframes on a list and add the columns like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame


data = {'COUNTRY': ['country1', 'country2', 'country3'],
    '2018': [12.0, 27, 35],
    '2019': [23, 39.6, 40.3],
    '2020': [35, 42, 56]}

df_list = [DataFrame(data), DataFrame(data), DataFrame(data),
           DataFrame(data), DataFrame(data), DataFrame(data), 
           DataFrame(data)]


def change_dataframes(data_frames=None):

    for df in data_frames:

        df = df.loc[:, ['COUNTRY', '2018', '2019']]

        df.replace({':': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
        df.replace({' ': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)

        pd.to_numeric(df['2018'], downcast="float")
        pd.to_numeric(df['2019'], downcast="float")

    return data_frames
```

Answer (score 0):

Using nunvie's answer as a base, here is another option for you:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'COUNTRY': ['country1', 'country2', 'country3'],
    '2018': ['12.0', '27', '35'],
    '2019': ['2:3', '3:9.6', '4:0.3'],
    '2020': ['35', '42', '56']
}


df_list = [pd.DataFrame(data) for i in range(5)]


def data_prep(df: pd.DataFrame):
    df = df.loc[:, ['COUNTRY', '2018', '2019']]

    df.replace({':': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
    df.replace({' ': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)

    df['2018'] = pd.to_numeric(df['2018'], downcast="float")
    df['2019'] = pd.to_numeric(df['2019'], downcast="float")

    return df


new_df_list = map(data_prep, df_list)
```

The improvements (in my opinion) are as follows. First, it is more concise to use list comprehension for the test setup (that's not directly related to the answer). Second, `pd.to_numeric` doesn't have `inplace` (at least in pandas 1.2.3). It returns the series you passed if the parsing succeeded. Thus, you need to explicitly say `df['my_col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['my_col'])`.

And third, I've used `map` to apply the `data_prep` function to each `DataFrame` in the list. This makes `data_prep` responsible for only one data frame and also saves you from writing loops. The benefit is leaner and more readable code, if you like the functional flavour of it, of course.